# Is there a Star Trek audio book read by Brent Spiner?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu, audio-book

I have already heard the audio book *[Imzadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imzadi#Other_versions)* as read by Jonathan Frakes, as well as *Imzadi II* read by the actor who plays Gowron and I am looking forward to hearing *Mosaic* read by Kate Mulgrew. So, as a big Data fan, I am looking for a story focused on this character and hopefully interpreted by Brent Spiner.

**Are there any audio books (of Star Trek stories) read by Brent Spiner?**

Comment: I can't find any. He's done a few narrations but no Star Trek novels I can find.

Comment: [Fan Fiction: A Mem-Noir: Inspired by True Events](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/56269181) - *"a fictitious noir detective story about Spiner dealing with a crazed, murderous fan who claims to be the fictitious Lal, the android daughter of Data in the third-season TNG episode - primarily narrated by Spiner"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Nope.

I Tweeted him about it. His answer:

> [No](https://twitter.com/BrentSpiner/status/939539972951912449)

> **tombquestwiki:** Hey @BrentSpiner! :) I'm a member of a #ScienceFiction & #Fantasy online community, and one of our members is wondering if you've ever narrated a #StarTrek audio book. If you could tell us yes/no, that would be awesome! :)
>
> **BrentSpiner**: No

Answer (score 6):

According to this [extensive list](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Audiobook) of Star Trek audiobooks on Memory Beta (the companion site to Memory Alpha), no, there is no audiobook read by Brent Spiner.

(For reference, [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com) is the largest wiki-style site about Star Trek canon works (and considered to be widely authoritative and reliable), Memory Beta is the companion site for "licensed Star Trek works, including novels, comic books, RPG sourcebooks, video games and any other licensed works" - so basically any works that aren't the shows themselves. If anyone knows about Star Trek audiobooks, I'd expect Memory Beta to have the information!)